# How can I rename columns when using combine in Julia DataFrame for many functions?

Tags: julia, dataframes.jl

what's wrong with the following sintaxis:

combine(gpd, :SepalWidth .=> [mean, sum] => [:mymean, :mysum] )

given that gdp is groupedDataFrame, and given that I want the columns :mymean and :mysum

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a dot in broadcasting. The following should work:

```
combine(gpd, :SepalWidth .=> [mean, sum] .=> [:mymean, :mysum])
```

*EDIT*

A crucial part of learning how to debug complex expressions in DataFrames.jl mini language is to understand that one can always check how broadcasting will handle the passed expression stand alone.

In this case you have:

```
julia> :SepalWidth .=> [mean, sum] .=> [:mymean, :mysum]
2-element Vector{Pair{Symbol}}:
 :SepalWidth => (Statistics.mean => :mymean)
 :SepalWidth => (sum => :mysum)
```

so as you can see the result is a vector of two correct transformation operations.

Now let us have a look at:

```
julia> [:SepalWidth, :SepalLength] .=> [mean] => [:mymean1, :mymean2]
2-element Vector{Pair{Symbol, Pair{Vector{typeof(mean)}, Vector{Symbol}}}}:
  :SepalWidth => ([Statistics.mean] => [:mymean1, :mymean2])
 :SepalLength => ([Statistics.mean] => [:mymean1, :mymean2])
```

This is clearly incorrect - as you try to store the result of `mean` as two columns. Instead if you write e.g.:

```
julia> [:SepalWidth, :SepalLength] .=> mean .=> [:mymean1, :mymean2]
2-element Vector{Pair{Symbol, Pair{typeof(mean), Symbol}}}:
  :SepalWidth => (Statistics.mean => :mymean1)
 :SepalLength => (Statistics.mean => :mymean2)
```

all is correct again.

Interestingly, in some cases you can omit a dot in broadcasting (but this is rare). For instance:

```
julia> [:SepalWidth, :SepalLength] .=> mean .=> identity
2-element Vector{Pair{Symbol, Pair{typeof(mean), typeof(identity)}}}:
  :SepalWidth => (Statistics.mean => identity)
 :SepalLength => (Statistics.mean => identity)

julia> [:SepalWidth, :SepalLength] .=> mean => identity
2-element Vector{Pair{Symbol, Pair{typeof(mean), typeof(identity)}}}:
  :SepalWidth => (Statistics.mean => identity)
 :SepalLength => (Statistics.mean => identity)
```

give you exactly the same result (in this case the `identity` part means that you reuse the input column name as output column name). The result with `=>` and `.=>` in the second part is the same since the second and third of the whole expression have a single element.

Comment: Thank you. I was wondering why the dot is not need in combine(gpd, [:SepalWidth, :SepalLength] .=> [mean] => [:mymean1, :mymean2])

Comment: I have added some more explanations. I hope you will find them helpful.

Comment: Thank you Bogumił Kamiński for you support in the Julia community.